# Variable passed to each() is not an array or object

Tags: php

I really don't understand why I'm getting this error or how to fix it!
Variable passed to each() is not an array or object on line-

```
while(list($key,$value) = each($_FILES['images']['name']))
```

Full code-

```
$max_no_img=4; // Maximum number of images value to be set here
$imgs_names = array('CV', 'Research Plan', 'Degree Transcript', 'GRE Scores');

echo "<form method=post action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
echo "<table border='0' width='400' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' align=left>";
for($i=1; $i<=$max_no_img; $i++){
echo "<tr><td>".$imgs_names[$i-1]."</br</td><td>
<input type=file name='images[]' class='bginput'></td></tr>";
}

echo "<tr><td colspan=2 align=center><input type=submit value='Submit'></td></tr>";
echo "</form> </table>";

while(list($key,$value) = each($_FILES['images']['name']))
{

echo $key;
echo "<br>";
echo $value;
echo "<br>";
if(!empty($value)){   // this will check if any blank field is entered
$filename =rand(1,100000).$value;    // filename stores the value

$filename=str_replace(" ","_",$filename);

$add = "upload/$filename";   // upload directory path is set

copy($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key], $add); 
echo $add;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try `var_dump($_FILES);` and put the output in your question

Answer (score 1):

`$_FILES['images']['name]` is not an array, `$_FILES['images']` is.

So

```
while (list($key, $object) = each($_FILES['images']))
{
    //use $object['name'] or $object['tmp_name']
}
```

Comment: It means you have not uploaded files, or the input field in your html does not match the `images` name

Comment: the files are in my folder'upload' and  <input type=file name='images[]'

Answer (score 0):

`$_FILES['images']['name']` is not an array! It is a value inside the array.

If you want to iterate over the files, you should:

```
while(list($key,$value) = each($_FILES['images']) {
 (...)
}
```